# How access global static variable from other process

Tags: android

I am developing an application where my application is running com.application process and My service is running com.applicion.service process (declered in manifest file) .

But I have a public static boolean variable  in com.applicion.servic process and want to access it value updated on com.application.

Is there any way to do it ..

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is they both are under one application, why dont you access it via CLASS_NAME.STATIC_VARIABLE_NAME,

if they are process which belong to two different application, then AIDL/Messanger or binders are the only option you have to do the same.

Comment: If on the same application but with 2 different processes (made though android:process="xyz" in androidmanifest.xml) it doesn't work to use CLASS_NAME.STATIC_VARIABLE_NAME. The value when accessing from process xyz doesn't hold the value set in the main process.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem my Service was running on a different process and I can't seem to get the static variable that belongs to the Service in my activity.
After making the Service and the activity run on the same process I could get the static variable> so in the end please be aware that different process don't seem to have access to static variables>
Hope this helps someone>

Answer (score 0):

I store global available information in a singleton class. Whenever I update the variable in an activity I also write it into my singleton class.

This way I can access it from anywhere I like.

Comment: this solution does not work when first process access singleton it makes its own object and when you getInstance in other process it makes its own object so it will not work in multi process i have tested it